# Receive an object with null attributes at back end when passing json via put request

Tags: java, spring

Basically what I want to do is to write an HTTP put method to update just a single attribute(object), but when I test this using postman, it threw a nested NullPointerExeption(I have white null validation with this attribute, but not with its sub-attributes).
Here is part of the code:

```
 @Override
    public int setProfile(long id, Profile profile) {
        Optional<Candidate> optional = findById(id);
        optional.ifPresent(c -> {
            c.setProfile(profile);
            updateById(id, c);
        });
        return optional.isPresent() ? 0 : 1;
    }
```

controller:

```
 @PutMapping(path = "/setProfile/{id}")
    public void setProfile(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody Profile profile){
        service.setProfile(id, profile);
    }
```

When I passed this "profile", I got a not-null profile object, but when I wanted to use smth like profile.getName(), it returned null. The weird thing is even if I passed a null like this:

```
{ "profile": null }
```

I still got the same thing(profile was not null, but profile.getName() is null)

Thank you for reading this question:)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the name of attributes of Profile in your java class and attributes in JSON have same names.

Also when you pass JSON like   `{ "profile": null }` it will call No argument constructor of Profile java class and hence you see Profile as not null, which is expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed this problem, it's just because I was so stupid that I used the wrong json format XD

Answer (score -1):

You should check your entities because I get this problem and I resolved it when I check the ID.